# Asking project manager to put me in another project

Tags: project-management, relationships

Sorry for my english first. I am a programmer and I am working in a big outsourcing company, that provides programmers for other companies. Right now I am in a really bad project without any prospects and I don't have any skills progress here.
We are in a good relationship with my project manager, the problem is that the current project isn't finished (we are doing some integration stuff for our client and this work will end in 2020) and I entered this project about 7 months ago.
How can I politely ask my PM to put me in another project?

Comment: So the problem is that you don't want to work on a big project?

Comment: No, I don't want to work on the current project, because I don't see any perspective here. My salary and grade will not be increased since we are not using any technologies or programming languages.

Comment: Do you have another project picked out that you'd like to be on?  I'm thinking it will go over better if you can say "I'd really like to be on that project" instead of "I don't like working on this project".

Comment: Actually no. Project managers and company choose projects for us. However it is possible to ask to change the project.

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/142308/edit) to remove the bit about "the problem is that the current project isn't finished (we are doing some integration stuff for our client and this work will end in 2020) and I entered this project about 7 months ago" if that's not relevant. Also, I think you mean 'prospects' rather than 'perspectives'.

Comment: I'm with @JoeStrazzere. I was in exactly this position a few months ago so I reached out to my manager (from my company, not the client) and was transitioned off pretty painlessly.

Comment: @DaveG: I disagree there. Asking to be moved from the current project but not specifying where to be moved to makes it a lot easier for OP's manager to move OP (since he's not requesting a particular move). It's also a matter of intention. Asking to be on another specific project can be inferred to be wanting something even better (which can be blocked as being non-essential), as opposed to simply wanting to move away from something that simply isn't a match for you (which is a much bigger indicator that OP needs the move).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Workplace question, like many others, where the answer is "have a conversation."

Talk to your manager about this. Mention you don't think you're living up to your potential and you'd like to do more challenging work. Subtly make it a **business opportunity** for him: suggest that your company could improve its quality of service by giving you harder work to do.

He's unlikely to agree to transfer you instantly. He will probably say "we have to finish this project first."  But he will know you want to do more. And he will keep you in mind when something else opens up.

Almost all companies and managers like ambitious people. (as long as you're not trying to take the manager's job!) So if you're polite, and you can take "no" for a short-term answer, you can hardly go wrong by asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not well thought out in my opinion.

Why should PM reward you for being self centered and selfish?

Unfortunately every project has problems and issues.  Your time is better spent resolving project issues for your PM and team.  You’ll build your credibility and trustworthiness which will result in more challenging assignments

Comment: Current project issues do not depend on me. They caused by the managers from client side. From my side - I am doing everything well and I don't have any issues about my work quality.